# Why am i getting a PEAK_RETURN_CODE_NOT_FOUND Error when trying to start a camera using ROS and SSH?

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, ssh, errors

I am working on a project where I want to control sensors and a camera connected to an Ubuntu 20.04 system. To avoid using the terminal on the Ubuntu system directly, I want to use buttons connected to a Raspberry Pi to control the sensors and camera over an SSH Ethernet connection. I have set up everything, and most functionalities are working fine, but now the following error occurred:

When running the bash script './bash_ros_starten_kamera.sh' over SSH from the Raspberry Pi, which contains the following code:

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash;
cd /home/hauke/catkin_ws;
source devel/setup.bash;
rosrun kamera_package pub_img_node;"
```

I get the following error message, and the camera doesnt start:

```
Error-Code: 11 (PEAK_RETURN_CODE_NOT_FOUND)| Error-Description:
GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH environment variable not found! Please set 
this path to the CTIs.
```

The weird thing for me is that if I run the './bash_ros_starten_kamera.sh' on the Ubuntu terminal directly, I don't get the error, and the camera starts as intended. The error only occurs when using the SSH connection from the Raspberry Pi. Also, I can control the other sensors using the SSH connection without any problems.

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to change much on the camera setup, but since the error only occurs when using the SSH connection, I am hoping to find a solution regarding the SSH connection.

Thanks in advance. Any help is welcome.